# Reading values from file and storing to different struct in C

Tags: c

I have a file of following format

```
[KeyString1]
Value1,Value2,Value3
<blankline>
[KeyString2]
Value1,Value2a,Value3a
```

Now I want read values which belongs to KeyString1 and KeyString2 separately and store in different Structure.

This is what i have tried till now

```
enum VAR_TYPE
{
    VAR_KeyString1,   
    VAR_KeyString2, 

};
int main(void) {

    FILE *fp;
    char temp[512];
    int  t_scanType;  

    if ((fopen_s(&fp, "/text.txt", "r")) != NULL) {
        return(-1);
    }
    t_scanType = -1;
    while(fgets(temp, 512, fp) != NULL)
    {
        if (temp == " ") {
            continue;
        }

        if ((strstr(temp,"[KeyString1]")) != NULL) {
            t_scanType=VAR_KeyString1;
            continue;
        }
        if ((strstr(temp,"[KeyString2]")) != NULL) {
            t_scanType=VAR_KeyString2;
            continue;
        }


        switch(t_scanType)  
        {
        case VAR_KeyString1:
          /* Store Values to specific structure */
            break;

        case VAR_KeyString1:
           /* Store Values to specific structure */
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        fclose(fp);
        return(0);
    }
}
```

The above code is only able to store the first values which is under [KeyString1] and then it will exit the loop. Looking for any suggestion for my problem.

Comment: Just so you know, the condition `temp == " "` will *never* be true. You compare two pointers that will never be the same. To compare strings you use the `strcmp` function. And to see if a line is empty you strip all leading and trailing whitespace (something you should probably do anyway) and check if the length is zero.

Comment: Your `return(0)` is in your while loop. At the end of the first iteration, your program quit with return value 0. Just put `return(0)` after the bracket (and the same for `fclose(fp)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (temp == " ") {
    continue;
}
```

is a newline check so it should be

```
if (temp[0] == '\n') {
    continue;
}
```